Cross-compile SBT project for different JDK versions
How do I configure SBT to cross compile my (Scala) project for different JDK versions? say JDK 11 and 17.
Is the only way to achieve that is manually building like so:
sbt -java-home "$JAVA11_HOME" package
sbt -java-home "$JAVA17_HOME" package

Isn't there anything that SBT supports natively? I am seeing a crossJavaVersions setting but it does not seem to be honored. I am seeing this warning too:
[warn] there's a key that's not used by any other settings/tasks:
[warn]
[warn] * ThisBuild / crossJavaVersions
[warn]          <...file...>

Anybody successfully configured SBT to build against different JDK versions?

P.S: I am on SBT 1.9+ and Scala 2.12

You could use https://github.com/sbt/sbt-projectmatrix with a custom axis.

The article Baeldung - Enforcing the JVM Version in an SBT Project, might help you to explore some other options apart of the one suggested by @GaëlJ

Thanks, I will take a look at sbt-projectmatrix.
